# In XML with XSLT Change an attribute according to a sub child value

Tags: xslt

I have a problem with an XML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <actesCCAM>
         <acteCCAM action="suppression"
                   facturable="oui">
            <executant>
               <medecins>
                  <medecinExecutant principal="oui">
                     <medecin>
                        <numeroAdeli>999999999</numeroAdeli>
                     </medecin>
                  </medecinExecutant>
               </medecins>
            </executant>
         </acteCCAM>
      </actesCCAM>
```

I need to:
Change attribute value `facturable="oui"` in `facturable="non"` if the adeli code is `<numeroAdeli>999999999</numeroAdeli>` And also add a value like:

```xml
<acteCCAM><VALEUR>a new value</VALEUR></acteCCAM>
```

i work with a XSLT like that, and try different solution but still not working. I'm very new in XSLT and use it rarely:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>

 <xsl:param name="facturableNON" select="'ZZZZ'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="acteCCAM/executant/medecins/medecinExecutant/medecin[numeroAdeli=999999999]">
      <xsl:template match="acteCCAM/@facturable">
        <xsl:attribute name="facturable">
            <xsl:value-of select="$facturableNON"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:template>

    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates cannot be nested. Instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="acteCCAM/executant/medecins/medecinExecutant/medecin[numeroAdeli=999999999]">
      <xsl:template match="acteCCAM/@facturable">
        <xsl:attribute name="facturable">
            <xsl:value-of select="$facturableNON"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:template>
```

try:

```
<xsl:template match="acteCCAM[executant/medecins/medecinExecutant/medecin/numeroAdeli=999999999]/@facturable">
    <xsl:attribute name="facturable" select="$facturableNON"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I try your suggest in freeformater but an error occur because the attribute is edited/created after child. Here the comment:  `An attribute node (facturable) cannot be created after a child of the containing element. Most recent element start tag was output at line 11 of module`

Comment: You are doing something that I am not: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZS.